# I need help to return

Tags: java, return, return-value

Im in progress making my first GUI program, and run into a little problem. I need to return the String value, so i can use it in the method "saying". This part is a sub class - a class built in another class..
The error return value; gets is: void methods cant return values. I know i have to replace void, but with what?? regards Oliver

```
private class Eventhandler implements ActionListener{
    double amount;


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String string = "";
        String string1 = "";

        if(event.getSource()==item1)
            string=String.format(event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource()==item2)
        string1=String.format(event.getActionCommand());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);

        double fn = Double.parseDouble(string);
        double sn = Double.parseDouble(string1);
        double amount = fn + sn;

        String value = Double.toString(amount);

        return value;


    }

}
public void saying(){
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to override the `actionPerformed` method, you can't. The return type of the method **must** be void.

Comment: public String actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){}

Comment: @Dimentar You can't do that. Have you read the other answers here?

Comment: Posted before other answers, after that reloaded the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, you can't return anything from `actionPerformed` because that's specified in the `ActionListener` interface. Even if you could, it wouldn't do you any good, because you're not the one calling the `actionPerformed` function.

What you want to do is give the parent class `value`, somehow. One way to do this is to have `value` be a field on the parent class. Then you can set it from the `actionPerformed` function:

```
private class ParentClass {
    private String value;

    //... stuff ...

    private class Eventhandler implements ActionListener{
        double amount;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            //... stuff ...

            ParentClass.this.value = Double.toString(amount);
        }
    }

    public void saying(){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Note that you can't do `this.value = value` in the inner class, because `this` in that funcion refers to the `Eventhandler` instance. You have to use the `ParentClass.this` syntax to get the parent class's `this`. Replace `ParentClass` with the actual name of your parent class.

A better way might be to have a `setValue()` function on the parent class, which the inner `Eventhandler` class calls. It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an instance variable and can initilise it in `actionPerformed` method like below

```
private class Eventhandler implements ActionListener{
String value=''


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
      value="newvalue";
      // rest code goes here
   }
}
```

you can not change the return type of api defined method

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the String value elsewhere in your program:

Replace

```
public void saying(){
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

with

```
public void saying(String value){
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

And then change

```
return value;
```

To

```
saying(value);
```